# Cordova - providing just 1 primary key in DB?

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, cordova

my friend just told me, that cordova only supports 1 primary key per Table - is this true, or is he just to stupid to figure out, how to get it worked?

I didn't find anything about this in the www.

Maybe someone can tell me that?

KR!

Comment: consider the meaning of "primary"... it comes from the latin primus (first) and you only have one primus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Cordova's idea - it is SQL rule, that `each table can have only ONE primary key`:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if by multiple primary keys you mean a composite key, otherwise no. Cordova uses SQL Lite for its [database](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html)

> "window.openDatabase returns a new Database object.
>   This method will create a new SQL Lite Database and return a Database object."

For SQL Lite you can define a composite primary key as

```
CREATE TABLE something (column1, column2, column3, PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your subject you have mentioned "1 primary key in **DB**?", whereas in your description you have mentioned "1 primary key per **Table**". These are two different things.
To answer your question in the description.
A table can have only one Primary Key. It is nothing related to SQLite. It is common across all RDBMS.
A primary Key specifies which column should be unique and not null.
It also creates index for that column
You can also specify another column to behave like a primary key i.e providing a **UNIQUE** contraint.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard and fast rule that every `DATABASE` of the world will support only `1 primary key` per `table`. So it doesn't matter whether it is `Cordova` or `somthing else` it will always support only 1 primay key in a table.